# return the two last record in erlang

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have this record :

```
-record(person, {id, firstname, lastname}).
```

and this table contains this kind of values :

```
1  anis    hila
2  samir   alagi
3  marwen  fares
4  sana    gabsi
5  safa    sassi
```

I want to develop a function which return the last two record of the table  person

meaning return just :

```
4  sana    gabsi
5  safa    sassi
```

I have a code which return the last id

```
Key=mnesia:last(person).
```

can someone help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
LastKey = mnesia:last(person)
SecondLastKey = mnesia:prev(person, LastKey)
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but we should add the transaction in the code because the function is expected to be called in a transaction context

Comment: So, did you look at [`mnesia:transaction`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#transaction-2)?

Answer (score 1):

To execute something in a transaction, you only have to define a function that does what you want and pass this function as argument of a mnesia transaction.

the function to get the last N person:

```
getlast(N) ->
    % get list of the last N Keys in reverse order
    Keys = lists:foldl(fun(_Num,Acc) -> [mnesia:prev(person,hd(Acc))|Acc] end, [mnesia:last(person)],lists:seq(2,N)),
    % get the list of the last N records in correct order and return
    lists:foldl(fun(Key,Acc) -> [mnesia:read(person,Key)|Acc] end, [],Keys).
```

the transaction to get the last 2 elements

```
Trans = fun() -> ?MODULE:getlast(2),
Result = mnesia:transaction(Trans).
```

*Note: I didn't test this code so it may content some errors. I'll check it tonight.*